# Concatenating all strings in a module

Tags: python

I have prepared the following file (`unicode_strings.py`) with some unicode strings that I want to use for testing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Refer to http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/unicode.txt

GREEK    = u'ΑΒΓΔ ΕΖΗΘ ΙΚΛΜ ΝΞΟΠ ΡΣΤΥ ΦΧΨΩ αβγδ εζηθ ικλμ νξοπ ρςτυ φχψω'
ACCENTS  = u'àáâãäåæç èéêë ìíîï ðñòóôõö øùúûüýþÿ ÀÁÂÃÄÅ Ç ÈÉÊË ÌÍÎÏ ÐÑ ÒÓÔÕÖ ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß'
CURRENCY = u'¤ $ ¢ € ₠ £ ¥'
...
```

So in my test file I can do:

```
from unicode_strings import GREEK

def test1():
    print GREEK
```

Now I want to implement a `test_all`:

```
def test_all():
    print ALL_UNICODE
```

How can I define `ALL_UNICODE` so that it is a concatenation of all strings (all variables) defined in `unicode_strings.py`. I do not want to define this manually, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your variables are uppercase names, and you didn't import any other such strings from elsewhere, you could use:

```
_uppercase = [k for k in dir() if k.isupper()]
ALL_UNICODE = ' '.join(map(globals().get, _uppercase))
```

This will concatenate all unicode strings bound to uppercase names in the current module global namespace.

I switched to using `dir()` here as that's a little less verbose than looping over `list(globals())`; you cannot loop with a list comprehension over `globals()` itself as list comprehension variables are injected into the global namespace *during* the loop, changing the size of the `globals()` dictionary during iteration.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not guaranteed: I am using uppercase names for constants all around my code (hopefully that is accepted practice). What is known is that I want to concatenate *all* variables coming from that file

Comment: @gonvaled: this only concatenates variables *in that file*. `globals()` applies only to one module.

Comment: Aha! I misunderstood you before. That could be it! Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
ALL_UNICODE = ' '.join([item for item in dir(unicode_strings) if not item.startswith("__")])
```

Comment: I prefer that in the module itself, as Martin has suggested.